# Cannot find module 'reflect-metadata'

Tags: angular, angular-module

Quando vou instalar o angular 2 usando:

```
ng new angular-teste
```

Recebo o erro:

> Cannot find module 'reflect-metadata'

O que pode ser?

Answer (score 1):

`NPM` deve ser atualizado para v3. Versões anteriores causarão este erro.

Para atualizar sua versão:

```
npm install npm -g
```

[Referência](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2430).